# Mobile first menu starts opened on iPad vertical

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, menu, tablet

I have a problem with my mobile first menu for my website.

The website is this one: http://www.articaclima.it/chi-siamo

By inspecting it via browser, with Responsive Design Mode, it works very well.
By viewing it with an iPad (vertical), it does not work: the menu starts opened at loading of the page, and if I close it and then I scroll down the page, it reopens.

What going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have conflicting media sizes being used to expand and collapse the menu, present in your js and css. In genericFunctions.js:176, you have:

```
var mediasize = 700;
```

The subsequent code then shows and hides the menu relative to this media size. However, in your css, you are setting 768px as the breakpoint for almost all of your responsiveness. Specifically, for the menu, in head.css:129, you have:

```
#cssmenu ul{width:100%;display:none; position: relative; top: 0px;}
```

Long story short, your media breakpoints need to match. For simplicity, I'd recommend changing the js code mentioned above to:

```
var mediasize = 768;
```

This should prevent the menu being open on page load when in the range of 700-768px (iPad).

Comment: Hello, thank you, I changed var mediasize to 768, but it is still not working.

Comment: What specifically is not working? i just tested the updated site on breakpoints 700-768px and no longer see the menu open by default.

Comment: Because google chrome is the best browser I used, but it completely unuseful if it caches every single page, even if I told it not to do it.... it works. Thanks!